# Regex for URL rewriting

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm starting in the URL rewriting and for now I have only one rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w|\-)+/?$ ?o=$0
```

This rewrite `.../anything` into `?o=anything`.

Now I'm trying to do something that would rewrite `.../anything/article5` into `?o=anything&id=5`. How can I achieve this? Do I need to do a second rule or a more elaborated rule? Also, I'm not very good in regex so I'm struggling a little bit.

Comment: I suggest you to leave  your regexp as it is and using in PHP a simple `explode("/",$_GET["o"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^([\w|\-]+)/article([0-9]+)/?$ ?o=$1&id=$2
```

You have to wrap with squared brackets `[]` to defines a characters' series.
Then, `$0` contains the full query, `$1` the first capture group (`()`), `$2` the second, and so on.

So :

```
/anything/article5
```

Will transform :

```
?o=anything&id=5
```